# How to make seasonal Landsat TM image composites in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a Landsat TM ImageCollection and would like to know how to create a new collection composed of either image representatives or image composites for 3-month intervals. I know how to filter and reduce a collection, but I don't know how to build a time series of images (or composites) at a regular interval. The goal is to generate a cloud-free dataset to monitor intra-annual surface water area change.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of 2-month median composites at 3-month intervals:

```
// ### USER INPUT ##############################################################

// Define an area of interest.
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Point(-121.66682, 36.38355);

// Define start year and number of years to follow.
var startDate = '2008-01-01';
var nYears = 1;

// #############################################################################

// Make ee objects of date info.
startDate = ee.Date(startDate);
nYears = ee.Number(1);
var nMonths = nYears.multiply(12);

// Define function to mask out clouds and cloud shadows.
function fmask(img) {
  var cloudShadowBitMask = 1 << 3;
  var cloudsBitMask = 1 << 5;
  var qa = img.select('pixel_qa');
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return img.updateMask(mask);
}

// Get Landsat TM surface reflectance collection for region of interest and years.
var tmCol = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
  .filter(ee.Filter.and(
    ee.Filter.bounds(aoi),
    ee.Filter.date(startDate, startDate.advance(nYears, 'year'))));

// Apply cloud mask function.
tmCol = tmCol.map(fmask);

// Make a sequence of months to center intra-annual 2-month composites over.
var seq = ee.List.sequence(1, nMonths, 3);
var compList = seq.map(function(month){
  month = ee.Number(month);
  var center = startDate.advance(month, 'month');
  var t1 = center.advance(-1, 'month');
  var t2 = center.advance(1, 'month');
  var imgMed = tmCol.filterDate(t1, t2)
    .median();
  var nBands = imgMed.bandNames().size();
  return imgMed.set({
    'system:time_start': center.millis(),
    'nBands': nBands});
});

// Convert composite image List to an ImageCollection.
var compCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(compList);

// Remove images w/ no bands (can happen if there were no images for a date range).
compCol = compCol.filter(ee.Filter.gt('nBands', 0));

// Make a visualization collection to check.
var visCol = compCol.map(function(img){
  return img.visualize({
    bands: ['B5', 'B4', 'B2'],
    min: 100,
    max: 3500})});

// Set animation arguments.
var gifParams = {
  'region': aoi.buffer(2000).bounds(),
  'dimensions': 512,
  'crs': 'EPSG:3857',
  'framesPerSecond': 3,
  'format': 'gif'
};

print(visCol.getVideoThumbURL(gifParams));
print(ui.Thumbnail(visCol, gifParams));
```

Script link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/3a95c2ce6c22523789a74085310a4d56

Comment: Hi, Thanks for sharing the code. I used a part of this code to create a filtered image collection. However, despite applying the cloud mask, most images in the new collection are distorted and my results for the surface area of the selected reservoir are presumably wrong. I guess if I increase the number of months to apply reducer, the image collection will be better. Can you suggest something? Here is the link to my code. 
 https://code.earthengine.google.com/7d5e1261139e6ab6e943a746de24d7e0