# Applying temporal water masks to temporal Landsat composites

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, mapping, otsu

My goal is to create monthly water masks using an NDWI index with Landsat. Additionally, the [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c839df7d4c6ee21f880d9b4c92de2a37) should allow a user to select their own temporal window, but in this case the goal is monthly. In addition to that, the goal is to create monthly Landsat compsites of NDVI index. I am trying to map `updateMask(mask)` to the monthly image collection of Landsat NDVI composites to apply the monthly MNDWI water masks. This is followed by the calculation of an Otsu threshold. Then the final result should be an a monthly time series of Landsat NDVI compsites that are thresholded. The error is that I am trying to updateMask with an image collection to another image collection. This error makes sense. I just don't know how can I incorporate an `updateMask(mask)` function from one image collection to another Image collection on a monthly basis? Some of this work is adapted from a [script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?accept_repo=users/geethensingh/Singh_etal_2020) related to this [paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/12/24/4021) and this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340696/how-to-make-seasonal-landsat-tm-image-composites-in-google-earth-engine).

```
// ### Functions  ##############################################################
//Function for acquiring Landsat SR image collection
function getLandsatImageCollection(studyArea,startDate,endDate,startJulian,endJulian,cloud){
  var ls;var l4SR;var l5SR;var l7SR;var l8SR;var l9SR;var out;
  
  var sensorBandDictLandsatSR =ee.Dictionary({L9: ee.List([1,2,3,4,5,6,8,17,18]),
                        L8 : ee.List([1,2,3,4,5,6,8,17,18]),
                        L7 : ee.List([0,1,2,3,4,5,8,17,18]),
                        L5 : ee.List([0,1,2,3,4,5,8,17,18]),
                        L4 : ee.List([0,1,2,3,4,5,8,17,18])
  });
  var bandNamesLandsatSR = ee.List(['SR_B1','SR_B2','SR_B3','SR_B4','SR_B5',
      'SR_B6','TEMP','QA_PIXEL', 'QA_RADSAT']);

  l4SR = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT04/C02/T1_L2")
      .filterDate(startDate,endDate)
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(startJulian,endJulian))
      .filterBounds(studyArea)
      .select(sensorBandDictLandsatSR.get('L4'), bandNamesLandsatSR);
  
  l5SR = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2")
      .filterDate(startDate,endDate)
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(startJulian,endJulian))
      .filterBounds(studyArea)
      .select(sensorBandDictLandsatSR.get('L5'),bandNamesLandsatSR);
  
  l7SR = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2")
      .filterDate(startDate,endDate)
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(startJulian,endJulian))
      .filterBounds(studyArea)
      .select(sensorBandDictLandsatSR.get('L7'),bandNamesLandsatSR);

  l8SR = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2")
      .filterDate(startDate,endDate)
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(startJulian,endJulian))
      .filterBounds(studyArea)
      .select(sensorBandDictLandsatSR.get('L8'),bandNamesLandsatSR);

  l9SR = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_L2")
      .filterDate(startDate,endDate)
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(startJulian,endJulian))
      .filterBounds(studyArea)
      .select(sensorBandDictLandsatSR.get('L9'),bandNamesLandsatSR);
      
  ls = ee.ImageCollection(l4SR.merge(l5SR)/*.merge(l7SR)*/.merge(l8SR).merge(l9SR))//dont include landsat 7 for now, maybe later
    .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUD_COVER',cloud))
    .map(function(i){

      var qaMask = i.select('QA_PIXEL').bitwiseAnd(parseInt('11111', 2)).eq(0);
      var saturationMask = i.select('QA_RADSAT').eq(0);

      var optical = i.select('^SR_B.*').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
      var thermal = i.select('TEMP').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);

      return i.addBands(optical, null, true).addBands(thermal, null, true).updateMask(qaMask).updateMask(saturationMask).clip(studyArea);
    });
  out = ls.set('system:time_start', ls.get('system:time_start')) ;
  return out.select('^SR_B.*');
}

//Function defining OTSU+CANNY detector (Refer to Donchyts et al. 2016)
//Return the DN that maximizes interclass variance in B5 (in the region).
var otsu = function(histogram) {
    histogram = ee.Dictionary(histogram);

    var counts = ee.Array(histogram.get('histogram'));
    var means = ee.Array(histogram.get('bucketMeans'));
    var size = means.length().get([0]);
    var total = counts.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
    var sum = means.multiply(counts).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
    var mean = sum.divide(total);

    var indices = ee.List.sequence(1, size);

    // Compute between sum of squares, where each mean partitions the data.
    var bss = indices.map(function(i) {
        var aCounts = counts.slice(0, 0, i);
        var aCount = aCounts.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
        var aMeans = means.slice(0, 0, i);
        var aMean = aMeans.multiply(aCounts)
            .reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0])
            .divide(aCount);
        var bCount = total.subtract(aCount);
        var bMean = sum.subtract(aCount.multiply(aMean)).divide(bCount);
        return aCount.multiply(aMean.subtract(mean).pow(2)).add(
            bCount.multiply(bMean.subtract(mean).pow(2)));
    });

    // Return the mean value corresponding to the maximum BSS.
    return means.sort(bss).get([-1]);
};

//Compute a threshold using Otsu method (bimodal)
function computeThresholdUsingOtsu(image, scale, bounds, cannyThreshold, cannySigma, minValue, debug) {
    // clip image edges
    var mask = image.mask().gt(0).focal_min(ee.Number(scale).multiply(3), 'circle', 'meters');

    // detect sharp changes
    var edge = ee.Algorithms.CannyEdgeDetector(image, cannyThreshold, cannySigma);
    edge = edge.multiply(mask);

    // buffer around NDWI edges
    var edgeBuffer = edge.focal_max(ee.Number(scale).multiply(80), 'square', 'meters');
    var imageEdge = image.mask(edgeBuffer);

    // compute threshold using Otsu thresholding
    var buckets = 100;
    var hist = ee.Dictionary(ee.Dictionary(imageEdge.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.histogram(buckets), bounds, scale)).values().get(0));

    var threshold = ee.Algorithms.If(hist.contains('bucketMeans'), otsu(hist), 0.3);
    threshold = ee.Number(threshold);

    if(debug) {
        // Map.addLayer(edge.mask(edge), {palette:['ff0000']}, 'edges', false);

        // print('Threshold: ', threshold);

        // print(ui.Chart.image.histogram(image, bounds, scale, buckets));
        // print(ui.Chart.image.histogram(imageEdge, bounds, scale, buckets));
        // Map.addLayer(mask.mask(mask), {palette:['000000']}, 'image mask', false);
    }

    return minValue !== 'undefined' ? threshold.max(minValue) : threshold;
}

//Edge mask function
function getEdge(mask) {
  return mask.subtract(mask.focal_min(1));
}

// ### USER INPUT ##############################################################
var aoi = ee.FeatureCollection("WWF/HydroATLAS/v1/Basins/level12").filterBounds(geometry)
Map.addLayer(aoi,null,'WWF HydroAtlas V1 Basin Level 12',false)

var gsw = ee.Image("JRC/GSW1_4/GlobalSurfaceWater").select('occurrence').clip(aoi).gte(5).focalMax(90, 'circle', 'meters');
Map.addLayer(gsw,null,'GSW Layer',false)

var slope = ee.ImageCollection("JAXA/ALOS/AW3D30/V3_2").select('DSM').mosaic().updateMask(gsw)
Map.addLayer(slope.lt(10),null,'JAXA ALOS DSM',false)

//1. Starting and ending date of long term Landsat time series
var cloud = null
var startYear = 1990 
var endYear = 2005 

var nYears = ee.List.sequence(startYear, endYear,1).size()
var nMonths = nYears.multiply(12)
print(nMonths,"Number of Months in Water Detction Time Series")

var startJulian = 0//
var endJulian = 364//

//calculate start year
if(startJulian > endJulian){endJulian = endJulian + 365}

var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(startYear,1,1).advance(startJulian,'day');
var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(endYear,1,1).advance(endJulian,'day');
  startDate = ee.Date(startDate)
  endDate = ee.Date(endDate)
print(startDate, endDate);


//2. The temporal frequency window in months (i.e. monghtly = 1, quarterly = 3, biannually = 6  
 var tempWindow = 1;
 
//3. geometry - upload custom geometry, draw a polygon, or draw a point
//add point to map in country of interest
Map.centerObject(geometry,15);
var bounds = ee.Geometry(Map.getBounds(true));

//4. User inputs for the canny edge detector and Otsu thresholding functions

//Identify best function inputs based on manual inspection, printing, etc. #todo
var debug = true;
var scale = 30;
var cannyThreshold = 0.99;
var cannySigma = 0.7;
var minValue = -0.1;

//5. Create the Landsat time series along with the mndwi and ndvi indices 
//Landsat Collection 2 Tier 1 SR Time Series
var Landsat = ee.ImageCollection(getLandsatImageCollection(aoi,startDate,endDate,startJulian,endJulian,cloud))
  .map(function(i){
    
    var date = i.date();
    var years = date.difference(ee.Date('1970-01-01'), 'year');
    
    var ndvi = i.normalizedDifference(['SR_B4', 'SR_B3']).rename(['NDVI']);
    var ndvi95 = ndvi.reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([95])).rename('NDVI_P95')
    var mndwi = i.normalizedDifference(['SR_B2', 'SR_B5']).rename(['MNDWI']);
    var mndwi95 = mndwi.reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([95])).rename('MNDWI_P95')
    
    return i.addBands(ndvi).addBands(ndvi95).addBands(mndwi)
    .addBands(mndwi95).addBands(ee.Image(years).rename('t')).float().addBands(ee.Image.constant(1))
    .updateMask(gsw);
  })

var WaterColl = function(image){
    var mndwi = image.select('MNDWI');
    return mndwi.updateMask(mndwi.gte(image.select('MNDWI_P95').abs().subtract(mndwi.abs())))};
  
  var numberOfWindows = endDate.difference(startDate,'month').divide(tempWindow).toInt();
  // generating a sequence that can be used as an indicator for my window step
  var waterImage = ee.ImageCollection(
    ee.List.sequence(0, numberOfWindows).map(function (num) { 
    num = ee.Number(num);
    // finding the start and end point of my windows
    var ini = startDate.advance(num.multiply(tempWindow), 'month');
    var end = startDate.advance(num.add(1).multiply(tempWindow), 'month');
      // calculating the quality mosaic mndwi of that window
    return Landsat.filterDate(ini,end).map(WaterColl)
    .merge(ee.Image.constant(0).rename('MNDWI').updateMask(gsw)).qualityMosaic('MNDWI')
    .selfMask().updateMask(slope.lt(10)).set('system:time_start',ini);
  }))
  print('Ensure all detected water images within Imagecollection contain a band', waterImage);

var waterMask = waterImage.map(function(i){
  var threshold = i.select('MNDWI').gte(0.0)
  return threshold.updateMask(threshold)
})

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Make a sequence of months to center intra-annual 1-month composites over.
var seq = ee.List.sequence(1, nMonths, 2);
var compList = seq.map(function(month){
  month = ee.Number(month);
  var center = startDate.advance(month, 'month');
  var t1 = center.advance(-1, 'month');
  var t2 = center.advance(1, 'month');
  var imgMed = Landsat.select('NDVI_P95').filterDate(t1, t2)
    .mosaic();
  var nBands = imgMed.bandNames().size();
  return imgMed.set({
    'system:time_start': center.millis(),
    'nBands': nBands});
});

// Convert composite image List to an ImageCollection.
var compCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(compList);
    // Remove images w/ no bands (can happen if there were no images for a date range).
    compCol = compCol.filter(ee.Filter.gt('nBands', 0))
    .map(function(i){
      var masked = i.updateMask(waterMask)
      var threshold = computeThresholdUsingOtsu(masked, scale, bounds, cannyThreshold, cannySigma, minValue, debug);
      return masked.updateMask(masked.gt(threshold))});
Map.addLayer(compCol)
```

Comment: look at `linkCollection` to "join" the two collections.

Comment: What property do you reccomend to link the source collection (monthly MNDWI) to the target collection (monthly NDVI)? Also, are you suggesting that after collection linking, to map the masks and then map the Otsu thresholding?

Comment: If both have the same length, you can create a new field (like ID) mapping over the collection using ee.List.sequence for setting that property. Then, you can merge them